# Segmentation fault: 11 running Xcode unit tests using xctool

Tags: xcode, sentestingkit

I'm trying to use `xctool` to run my Xcode unit tests from a Jenkins server for CI purposes.  When I run my tests via:

```
xctool -project MyApp.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp test -sdk iphonesimulator
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fxgsgucvulucjcbkdjllermhnvah/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAppTests.build/Script-FA92AE8E162C5E1900A410A1.sh: line 3: 10301 Segmentation fault: 11  "${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 139
```

If I remove the default `Run Script` that has:

```
# Run the unit tests in this test bundle.
"${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests"
```

from my Test target, the call to `xctool` works fine -- and I can still run my unit tests directly in Xcode via `Cmd+U`.

I've waded through a lot of searches trying to find the "correct" solution to this but haven't had any luck.  Is simply removing that default post build step that calls `RunUnitTests` acceptable?  What does that even do?